# Insert variable from script call into a string inside the script bash

Tags: bash

Say I have a script called `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -XY user@host -t 'cd /path/variable_to_insert/path_1;'
```

What I want to do is be able to call the script `bash test.sh` and give it the string that will replace `variable_to_insert` so if I needed "cow_face" the script would execute:

`ssh -XY user@host -t "cd /path/cow_face/path_1;"`

so in pseudocode...  `bash -insert "cow_face" test.sh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass an argument to your script.

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh -XY user@host -t "cd /path/${1:-default}/path_1;"
```

Then call it like so:

```
bash test.sh cow_face
```

The value after the - in `${1:-default}` will be a default value if no argument is passed. So if you call it with no argument it would cd to `/path/default/path_1`

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html

Comment: this is great! could you link documentation for where you learned this from? I may want expand this

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html Discusses positional parameters. In general that site is a great resource.

Comment: @atomsmasher Also just to let you know, you may already know this but if you give the script executable permissions by calling chmod +x test.sh, you won't need to run it by calling bash first.